# Changing the location of components in a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: The circuit]

As you can see in the figure, the author claims that the right circuit and the left circuit are equivalent.

However, in the left circuit, the 6-ohm resistor is connected to the 1-ohm resistor, and in the right circuit it isn't. In the left circuit it is connected in the two yellow markers, but in the right one, in the two right yellow markers.

In what conditions such replacement is allowed?

Comment: From the top-left corner, all the way around to the bottom-right corner, is all one node. There's just wires between them.

Answer (score 2):

The top-left and bottom-right yellow nodes are one and the same since there is only wire connecting them (passing through the red node).

Comment: But... there is a node between them...

Comment: No, there isn't. There is only wire, and wire itself cannot make up a node.

Comment: Doesn't it matter that the current is different between the points, because of the current source that connected to the node (marked in red)?

Comment: No, because ideal wires have no resistance and hence no voltage drop. The current could go back and forth and loop-the-loop through the wire and it would still all be the same node.

Comment: As both circuits are equivalent, we see that the resistors with 3 and 6 Ohm are in parallel, but also both are parallel to the series connenction of 1 and 2 Ohm.